# Map string array from resources to enum in android

Tags: java, android, android-resources

Let's assume we have string array in android resources, like that

```
<string-array name="vals">
    <item>item1</item>
    <item>item2</item>
    <item>item3</item>
</string-array>
```

is there any way to properly map it on enum in java?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991071/declare-java-enum-with-a-string-array